# php form does not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I try to do an insert into my database using a form but it fails.
My field type is longtext, because I want to add an iframe link.
Can someone help me?

Here is my source code :

```
if (isset($_POST['valider']))
{

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=horseblog;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$res = $connect->exec('INSERT INTO musique SET lien="'.$_POST['lien'].'"');
header("location:mainPage.php");
}
```

My form :

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post"  action ="ajoutMusic.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">LIEN :</label>
        <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="lien" style="margin-left: 5%;" /><br/><br/>

        <span style="width: 200px"></span>
    </div>
    <input  class="btn btn-warning"style="margin-left: 3%; "type="submit" name="valider" value="ajouter"><br/><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? Or say whay does not work exactly?

Comment: See also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491), and then use `→prepare()` and `→execute([…])` with placeholders instead.

Comment: If people would look up in the documentation I would be _soooo happy_. One does not simply merge an INSERT statement with an UPDATE statement.

Comment: it works when i do that directly in the phpmyadmin and when i do that with a simple text like 'test of insertion' but when i want to insert : <code><iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/139359277&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe><code> that doesnt work